# Update Sharepoint from Excel via ADO connection - Internal name issue

Tags: sql, excel, sharepoint, ado

I need to update a SharePoint table which has a field name with Spaces. The field name is called `Tracking log`
Unfortunately there are lot of reports already created that don't let me recreate this column with a different name, so I need to find a workaround to address this special name.

Lot of blogs point me to revise the internal name and check the name given when it was created, so I checked the List Setting menu for the whole URL path and see the following: 
https://sales.acs.com/SMS/_layouts/15/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7B686F9AF9%2DFB64%2D4AD9%2DA268%2D19A057C432DA%7D&Field=Tracking%5Fx0020%5Flog

Below is the script I've put together which runs perfectly fine for any other field without spaces in the name, but not specifically for this one.

```
Dim sSQL As String
' Build the connection string
sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & "DATABASE=" & sSHAREPOINT_SITE & ";" & "LIST=" & sDEMAND_ROLE_GUID & ";Authentication=Default;"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

' Open the connection.
With cn
.ConnectionString = sConn
.Open
End With

ID = "12345"
fieldName = "Tracking_x0020_log" 'Display view is "Tracking log", I've tried also with Tracking%5Fx0020%5Flog without luck


FieldValue = "Test"

'sSQL = "SELECT * FROM EMEA_SALES WHERE (APA_number='" & Format(ID, "#") & "');"
sSQL = "UPDATE EMEA_SALES SET " & fieldName & " = '" & FieldValue & "' WHERE (APA_number='" & Format(ID, "#") & "');"

rs.Open sSQL, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

The error I've got is:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

When I change the fieldname for any other without spaces is run smoothly.

Any clue will be appreciated. Thanks folks!

Comment: try putting brackets around the column with spaces in it  [column name with spaces]

Comment: Hi Brad! is working perfectly now!! Thank you so much!!